# Set WPF Application's size to overlay all Monitors

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, winforms, screen

My primary user-target are user with multiple screens.
My application should overlay all those screens. This is easy for users with screens standing next to each other, primary screen left. Then i can just set my program's `this.Left = 0` (same with Top) and set the width to the screens combined width.
Unfortunately not ever user has the same setup, so I have to make some dynamic code, that will place the window correctly on every setup.
What if the user has the primary screen to the right? What if he has the screens vertically? What if he has different resolutions and/or different scaling factors (DPI, 100%, 125%, ...) on each screen?

Can someone help me out write a C# Method that will place my window correctly to overlay every monitor? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This function will calculate the total number of screens connected and will give you the Dimensions.

```
                public   System.Drawing.Size GetTotalArea()
                    {
                   System.Drawing.Size SizeYouNeed = new Size(0,0);
                    foreach (var screen in Screen.AllScreens)
                   {
                    SizeYouNeed.Height+=screen.WorkingArea.Height;
                     SizeYouNeed.Width +=screen.WorkingArea.Width;

                        }
                         return SizeYouNeed;
                          }
```

Comment: This is not what I want. E.g. the user has two 1080p Monitors next to each other, then I want my window to be 3840x1080 in size. If he has two 1080p monitors vertically, I want my window to be 1920x2160.